# Grails: easiest way to persist hashmap in GORM

Tags: grails, hashmap, blob, grails-orm

I am generating a big nasty ruby-style hashmap, and rather than re-factor to well described objects i just want to hang this beastliness quickly onto a domain object.  Is there any EASY way to store this hashmap without having to write a bunch of .toBytes getters and setters?

```
class EasyObjectStorer{

  Object thing
}
```

Would be just super. So I can go:

```
def makeThisThing = new EasyObjectStorer()
makeThisThing.thing=['allala':'laalla','etc':'etc']
makeThisThing.save(failOnError:true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just store it as a String and use evaluate() to hydrate it back to a hashmap.

```
def a = "['allala':'33','etc':'1']"
def result = evaluate( a )
println result.etc
```

Be aware your keys need to be 'strings' using this method.

Comment: My example may be oversimplified... the hash map is the result of a function.  Could I convert an already existing hashmap to string and if so would it actually be any better than converting it to byte?

Comment: Converting to string seems simpler ->